# SQL Server 2012 permissions issue during bulk load of CSV file

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I had gone through many other questions and They haven't answered by specific question. I understand the error that it is expecting the file to be present in the SQL server.

I have installed  SQL Server 2012 on my laptop and trying to bulk insert a CSV file from my local drive and I am getting the error

```
Msg 4801, Level 19, state 1, Line 1 
Cannot bulk load because the file could not be opened
```

After looking at a few answers I understand that this is a permissions issue but i have no idea how to resolve it. I am on windows 10 and using SQL server express 2012

Comment: Make sure you put the file in server and mention the server path

Comment: What command exactly are you using to do the bulk load?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server needs permission to the folder that the CSV file lives in.

You need to give permission to the `NT Service\MSSQLSERVER` account on that folder (or whatever account you created in your SQL Server install). If it still doesn't work after that, make sure that SQL Server has permissions to the file itself. You will run into that problem if the CSV file was created in a directory outside of the directory that you're giving SQL Server permissions to.

[Here is how to configure permissions on Windows folders](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219062.aspx)

[image: SQL Server Permissions]

Comment: Thanks. Will try and inform.

Comment: I think I am stuck at the Name not found for at the step 5 of the link you had posted. I am not able to search for the service  NT SERVICE\MSSQLSERVER

Comment: There's a more elegant way of doing this, I'm sure of it but do this: go to the SQL Server install directory, right click the DATA folder and check the permissions on it. That will tell you the account you installed SQL Server with. Could also be a problem that you're using express. I've never used it so I don't know if it behaves differently in that regard

Comment: I think I have to use MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS. Thanks!

Comment: So was that the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Put your CSV file other than C drive(Try to use D, E.....) Using the following BULK INSERT statement, you can insert bulk data into the database directly from a CSV file. The simplest version of the BULK INSERT query looks like that:

```
BULK INSERT dbo.YourDBTableName
FROM 'D:\YourFileName.csv'
WITH
(
FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
)
```

or you can handle transaction and rollback, a try catch block can be used like that:

```
EGIN TRANSACTION
BEGIN TRY
BULK INSERT dbo.YourDBTableName
FROM 'D:\FolderName\YourFileName.csv'
WITH
(
    FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
    ROWTERMINATOR = '\n',
    ROWS_PER_BATCH = 10000, 
    TABLOCK
)
COMMIT TRANSACTION
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
END CATCH
```

if one of two methods goes well, then you might have any of the following two problems:

1. **'C' drive permission problem**: In this case you have to give proper permission to the particular file/ folder.
2. **The file must be corrupted OR your code is not right**: In this case, try to open the file with notepad++ or any editor manually. If you can open the file then see the **FIELDTERMINATOR**, here i have use **coma(,)**. Some time **vertical var( | )** are used to separate the data. So change it if you need to.

Anothe important thing is, try to run the SQL server 2012 Management Studio as an **administrator** (righr-click the icon -> run as administrator)